# WIX: installing fragments to the same directory, same file names

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

In my wix installer I need to install some kind of addon dlls to a directory. There could be many addons, all are installed to the same directory. Each addon is a feature which could be chosen or not. Each addon is installed together with referenced dlls. The referenced dlls can be the same (both: name and contents) for two or more components. So it could be something like this:

Addon1:
Addon1.dll
Reference1.dll
Reference2.dll

Addon2:
Addon2.dll
Reference2.dll
Reference3.dll

If both features are selected, the installation result is:
Addon1.dll
Addon2.dll
Reference1.dll
Reference2.dll
Reference3.dll

I would like to make a separate fragment for each addon so that I can manage features properly. I can harvest files for each addon but the problem here are the same file names. A wix project containing such fragments doesn't compile.

I would like to avoid placing shared reference dlls to another common fragment because there could be many addons with very different dependencies between references.

Is there any way to dial with it differently?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I would do manually without automatic harvesting. Unless you have hundreds of AddOns this really isn't going to be much extra work and if you harvest them using heat and then embed the resulting wxs files into your project with some modification, it won't be too difficult at all. I suppose this will add more overhead if the AddOns change frequently but I would imagine that this won't happen all that often.

Comment: It's not hundreds of addons but it's quite many (tens) dependencies. The installers build is going to be integrated into the build process. So the solution, it seems, would be to put all references to one separate folder and to generate a common fragment from it, always deploying all references even if some of them are not needed. An alternative would be indeed to manually include the needed references but this is quite dangerous because tracking new dependencies when you work in team is hard. Someone always forgets to mention or to update the file itself and then the installed solution fails.